# How to separate php mvc controller directories for backend directory and frontend directory?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am struggling to separate controller directories that are responsible for backend controller and frontend controller so it can be easy for working with two parties of the application.
I use this directory structure.

```
    |APP( DIRECTORY )
    |---CONTROLLERS
            |-Home.php
            |-Error.php
    |---CORE
          |-Application.php
          |-Controller.php
    |---MODEL
          |-User.php
    |---PUBLIC
          |-index.php
          |.htaccess
```

I want to be able to create backend and frontend contollers directories like this.

```
    |---CONTROLLERS
        |---FRONTEND
                |-Somecontoller.php
        |---BACKEND
                |-Somecontoller.php|APP( DIRECTORY )
```

Thanks in advance.

// Application

```
   <?php 

    class Application
    {
        public $url = null;
        public $controller = null;
        public $controllerPath = '../CONTROLLERS/';
        public $modelPath = '../MODELS/';
        public $errorFile = 'Err.php';
        public $defaultFile = 'Home.php'; 

        public function BootApp() 
        {
            $this->parseUrl();

            if (empty($this->url[0])) 
            {
              $this->loadDefaultController();
              return false;
            }  

            $this->loadExistingController();
            $this->callControllerMethod(); 
        }

        public function setController($path)
        {
            $this->controllerPath = trim($path, '/') . '/';
        }

        public function setModel($path)
        {
            $this->modelPath = trim($path, '/') . '/';
        }

        public function parseUrl()
        {
            $this->url = isset($_GET['url']) ? $_GET['url'] : null;
            $this->url = str_replace('-', '', $this->url);
            $this->url = filter_var($this->url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
            $this->url = rtrim($this->url, '/');
            $this->url = explode('/', $this->url);
        }

        public function loadDefaultController()
        {
            require $this->controllerPath . $this->defaultFile;
            $this->controller = new Home();
            $this->controller->index();
        }

        public function loadExistingController()
        {
            $file = $this->controllerPath . $this->url[0] . '.php';
            if (file_exists($file)){
                  require $file;
                  $this->controller = new $this->url[0];
            } 
            else{
                  $this->error();
            }
        }

        public function callControllerMethod()
        {
            $this->controller->index(); 
        }



        private function error() 
        {
            require realpath($this->controllerPath . $this->errorFile);
            $this->controller = new Err();
            $this->controller->index();
            exit;
        }
    }
}
```

// PUBLIC / .htaccess

```
   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
      RewriteEngine On
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
      RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
   </IfModule>
```

// PUBLIC / index.php
<?php

```
    // SPL AUTOLOAD CORE, CONTROLLERS, MODELS
    $app = new Application();
    $app->BootApp();
    $app->setController('../CONTROLLERS/');
```